# How to stretch an image to 50% of the screen in css

Tags: html, css, layout

i have layout: https://www.behance.net/gallery/99127261/Webcor-Landing-Page-free-psd
And have problem with 2nd section "About us", I created 2 div and make it as flex box,
tryed set to img 50%, but uselles, get like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBd2f.jpg)

How i can make it as in layout?

code: `

```
<section class="about" id="about">
            <div class="about__description">
                <div class="desc-left">
                    <img src="./img/about.png" alt="WebCor-about" >
                </div>
                <div class="desc-right">
                    <h2>About us</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia id nulla autem maxime, dolore
                        aperiam possimus esse nisi laudantium dolores hic iste! Eligendi, recusandae laboriosam.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perspiciatis?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>`
```

css:

```
h2 {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    font-size: 3.7em;
}

.about {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.about__description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about__description p {
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.desc-left {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.desc-left img {
    width: 50%;
}

.desc-right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `width: 50vw;` That means 50% of your viewport width. The same is working for the height, then its `vh`.